# React, Docker, nginx deployment on my Domain

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

im running into an issue and i cannot resolve it since hours by now.

I just got a Server and a Domain, now i would love to deploy my react app dockerized.

**When i access my Domain via "http" im getting following output:**

`Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.`

**When i access my Domain via "https" im getting following output:**
"MY DOMAIN NAME" refused to connect

**When i access my Domain via "IPv4" im getting following output:**
502 Bad Gateway

**My Dockerfile:**

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:20 AS builder

# Set the working directory to /client inside the container where the UI will be located at
# as if we would use "cd" in linux, if the folder does not exist, it will create the folder under the given path
WORKDIR /usr/src/client

# Copy app files to workdir inside the docker container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies (npm ci makes sure the exact versions in the lockfile gets installed)
RUN npm ci

# Copy all of the project files into the docker container
COPY . .

# RUN the build after installing dependencies and the "COPY" of the whole source code
RUN npm run build

##########################
# Use the official Nginx base image with Alpine Linux as the base image for the final production container.
# Nginx will be used to serve the static files generated by the React app.
FROM nginx:alpine

# Set the working directory inside the container to /usr/share/nginx/html, where Nginx serves the static content.
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file that comes with the image.
# We will replace it with our custom configuration file.
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy the custom Nginx configuration file from the host (your machine) to the container.
# This configuration file will be used by Nginx to serve the React app and handle incoming requests.
COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Remove all the existing files in the /usr/share/nginx/html directory to clear any default content that Nginx might have placed there.
RUN rm -rf ./*

# Copy the production build files of the React app (generated in the previous build stage) from the "builder" stage into the /usr/share/nginx/html directory.
# This makes the built React app available to Nginx for serving.
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/client/build .

# Set the default command that will run when the container starts.
# This command starts Nginx in the foreground to serve the React app and keeps the container running.
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**My docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    frontend:
      stdin_open: true
      image: MY-IMAGE-NAME
      container_name: MY-CONTAINER-NAME-C
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
        - '8443:443'
      environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
      volumes:
        - /etc/nginx/certificates:/etc/nginx/certificates
```

**My nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name MY-DOMAIN.com;
    client_max_body_size 500m;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    client_max_body_size 500m;
    server_name MY-DOMAIN.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/MY-DOMAIN.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/MY-DOMAIN.com_private_key.key;
}
```

My Dockerized frontend is working as "localhost" but my nginx is as mentioned above, giving me weird results and i am wondering what i have done wrong.

I hope anyone can help

I followed a few youtube explanations and loads of google results but none of these did really help unless i did something wrong.

Comment: can you add the url which u used when accessing your domain? did you use `http:my-domain.com` only?

Comment: just for troubleshooting can you update ports mapping inside your docker compose from "8080:80" to "80:80" then share the reuslt

Comment: I don't think it's a good way to have single dockerfile for nginx and react app together, I recommend using 2 images one for nginx and the other one your react app

Comment: If you have any usefull link for a seperate configuration for an nginx webserver + react, i would appreciate it.

I did change the port to 80:80 in my docker-compose file and the result end up in:

Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

Comment: aha I see, that's mean you already have nginx server running in your server so you were using the one in your server not the one in your docker container, can you switch it off the one in your server?

Comment: you can check this here https://github.com/devopshint/docker-compose-react-nginx/tree/main

Comment: Alright, appearentley there was still an nginx instance running, i uninstalled it and removed it from the port 80.

Now after docker-compose down , docker-compose up -d --build, the error still have not changed.

Thank you for the github link, i will take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254635/discussion-between-omar-al-howeiti-and-terraya).

Comment: Thanks to Omar i could fix a few steps and accomplish my goal :)